# split a large file into small file based on pattern that can occur randomly Python

Tags: python, split

I have this large file with following content:

```
Column1 column2 column3
 345     367    Ramesh
 456     469    Ramesh
 300     301    Ramesh
 298     390    Naresh
 123     125    Suresh
 394     305    Suresh
 ......
 .....
```

Now, I want to split this file into small files based on the name in column3. Like this:

File1: Ramesh.txt

```
column1 column2 column3
345     367      Ramesh
456     469      Ramesh
300     301      Ramesh
```

File2: Naresh.txt

```
column1 column2 column3
298     390     Naresh
```

File3: Suresh.txt

```
Column1 column2 column3
123     125      suresh
394     305      suresh
```

and likewise. 
I wrote the following python codes and it worked:

```
def split_file(file1):
source=open(file1)
l=[]
header=0
header_line=""
file_count=0
for line in source:
    line=line.rstrip()
    a=line.split()
    if header==0:
        header_line=line
        header+=1
    else:
        if a[-1] not in l:
            l.append(a[-1])
            file_count+=1
            if file_count>1:
                dest.close()
            else:
                pass
            dest=open(a[-1],'a')
            dest.write(header_line+"\n"+line+"\n")
        else:
            dest.write(line+"\n")
source.close()
dest.close()
```

Now, my query is how can I modify these codes to work even if column3 is not sorted. For example:

```
Column1 column2 column3
345     367    Ramesh
123     125    Suresh
456     469    Ramesh
298     390    Naresh
300     301    Ramesh
394     305    Suresh
```

Shall I generate random variable as values (to handle the output file) with the name in column3 as keys. And then use this dictionary to open the file everytime script encounters the key? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest a short command-line solution for Unix-based OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than open and close file pointers on every line you could keep them opened until your work is done.

First create a dictionary for file pointers :

```
fps = {}
```

Then in the loop iterating your data file, if the file pointer doesn't exist, create it :

```
if a[-1] not in fps.keys():
    fps[a[-1]] = open(a[-1], 'a')
fps[a[-1]].write(line)
```

Then at the end of the loop you can close the file pointers :

```
for f in fps.values():
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_file(filename):
    dest = {}
    with open(filename) as source:
        header_line = next(source)
        for line in source:
            name = line.rstrip().split()[-1]
            if name not in dest:
                dest[name] = open(name + '.txt', 'w')
                dest[name].write(header_line)
            dest[name].write(line)
    for d in dest.values():
        d.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime example for the `groupby()` function of pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('dat.csv', delimiter="\s+")
for val, df in data.groupby(['column3']):
    df.to_csv(val + ".csv", sep='\t', index=False)
```

The steps are relatively simple:

1) Read the file with the correct delimiters (`\s+` stands for any number of whitespaces).

2) Loop through the groupy object which contains tuples of the form `(common value, dataframe for that value)`

2.1) Produce a file for each dataframe with the corresponding name.
(`index=False` just states that we don't want to print the index in the new files.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file handle for each value of `column3` and then just write it all to that file, e.g.:

```
import os

def split_file(path):
    file_handles = {}  # a map of file handles based on the last param
    target_path = os.path.dirname(path)  # get the location of the passed file path
    with open(path, "r") as f:  # open our input file for reading
        header = next(f)  # reads the first line to use as a header in all files
        for line in f:
            index = line.rfind(" ")  # replace with \t if you use tab-delimited files
            value = line[index+1:].rstrip()  # get the last value
            if not value:  # invalid entry, skip
                continue
            if value not in file_handles:  # we haven't started writing to this file
                # create a new file with the value of the last column
                handle = open(os.path.join(target_path, value + ".txt"), "a")
                handle.write(header)  # write the header to our new file
                file_handles[value] = handle  # store it to our file handles list
            else:
                handle = file_handles[value]
            handle.write(line)  # write the current line to the designated handle
    for handle in file_handles.values():  # close our output file handles
        handle.close()
```

Then you can run it with a simple:

```
split_file("your_file.dat")
```

And it will even respect file paths if you pass them.